# How to replace www. from url without breaking urls like www.someurlwww.com

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have been using .replace("www.", ""); in javascript, but today I was thinking that if an url contains www. in the last part (like someurlwww.com), that will also get replaced. How can I safely cleanup urls protocol+www.?

Comment: Depends on your input. Is it always `http://www.~` or can it be any valid URL

Comment: Where do you get the URL from? Also note that `'somesite.com' != 'www.somesite.com'`. Removing `www` can break the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
.replace(/^http:\/\/www./, "http://")
.replace(/^www./, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PePS7/7/

this should do the trick

```
value.replace(/[https*:\\]*www./,""));
```