# Redirect to a different domain for https

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, security

I'm using spring security, and I want to force HTTPS for a few urls.  However my cert is ona subdomain.

For example, if they hit http://**www**.mydomain.com/myaccount I would like them to be redirected to https://**secure**.mydomain.com/myaccount

What's the best way to accomplish this with spring security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the most efficient way but

```
if(URL.getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("https"))
 then replace "www." with " secure."
```

refer [how to replace www in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136707/how-to-replace-www-from-url-without-breaking-urls-like-www-someurlwww-com) for the second part